# How to validate forms which use the PrettyCheckable jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, checkbox

I've used [PrettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) to style some checkboxes. I want to validate them client side but I can't see how it would even work: looking at the DOM using FireBug, it seems that PrettyCheckable wraps the checkbox in a DIV and puts a graphic over the top in an `a` element, and toggles a "checked" class on the `a` -- without passing the click on to the hidden checkbox. So when the form is submitted, the checkbox isn't actually checked? Does it check them on the submit event?

Also going to post this to the GitHub for the plugin.

**EDIT**: despite the *appearance* that the field is not being checked when inspecting the DOM using FireBug, validation works just fine and the 'checked' property of the input *is* being set. My mistake. Leaving this here for reference. See below for Javascript validation recipes.

Comment: If the checkmark is not passed down to the core element then the plugin would be pretty useless.   How else would the Post or Get request know the status of that item?

Comment: Well I did suggest that maybe the check was added at form submit time. I'm not completely missing the point.

Comment: Having had a coffee and thinking about it, maybe the problem is that I can't see the checking and unchecking in Firebug. The Javascript posted by Hanlet Escaño below certainly works. I just can't see any change in the DOM in Firebug. False alarm I guess.

Comment: Please use the "delete" link in that case. Thanks.

Comment: I think I should edit the question and leave it, because other people might make the false assumption I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to check whether or not a CheckBox is checked. Check out this code:

```
$('input.myClass').prettyCheckable();
$(".prettycheckbox").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked"));
});
```

As you said, the checkbox is wrapped in a div, you just find the checkbox inside of it, and check the checked property.

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/SSWJu/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could for example do something like this.

```
var i = 0;
$('input.prettyCheckable').each(function(){
   var lnk = $(this).next().hasClass('checked') ? true : false;

   if(lnk){
      console.log('The checkbox '+i+' is checked!');
   }

   i++;
});
```

Or add a `click` event for `<a>` and check if it has class `checked`

Answer (score 0):

`$("#Checkbox1").prop("checked")`

returns true or false from original checkbox. Works for me with prettyCheckable.